# Typescript Dynamic call from string class name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have :

```
export Interface IFoo {
  execute(bar : Bar)
}

export class ClassA implements IFoo {
  execute(bar : Bar) { ... }
  ...
}
export class ClassB implements IFoo {
  execute(bar : Bar) { ... }
  ...
}
export class ClassC implements IFoo {
  execute(bar : Bar) { ... }
  ...
}
```

An interface `IFoo` that is implemented by 3 different classes `[ClassA, ClassB, ClassC]`.

Now i have user who will input in string that they would like to call a particular class
For example:

```
export class Qux {
  public runner(className : string) { 
    Object.call(className, 'execute'); // This should call execute in the given className
  }
}
```

Few preconditions, the user can ONLY pass in string class that is type of IFoo. Also runner will always call execute method in that class.

How can i accomplish that so that when user passes in

```
q = new Qux();
q.runner('ClassA')
>Executes ClassA's execute method
q.runner('ClassC')
>Executes ClassC's execute method
```

Thanks!!

Comment: A map (or function) string -> IFoo is probably easiest, especially if it’s a fixed set. Presumably the class will will have an instance created too, before the method is invoked, or..?

Comment: Yeah I was hoping not to use a Map to hold all my classes. That means Qux would have to have reference to all the classes ClassA, B, and C(thus causing dependency loop in my code) . I was hoping that that Qux would just instantiate and call dynamically.